# Inverse Laplace transform from a power series with finite radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laplace-transform

Suppose we are given some function $f(t)$ define on $t\in [0,\infty)$.   Then, the Laplace of this function is given by
\begin{align}
F(s)= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} f(t) dt
\end{align}
where $s=\sigma+i\omega$, and the inverst Laplace transform is given by
\begin{align}
L^{-1}[F(s)](t)=\frac{1}{ 2 \pi i} \lim_{T \to \infty} \oint_{c-iT}^{c+iT} e^{ts} F(s) ds,
\end{align} 
where $c$ is some real constant in the region of convergnce of $F(s)$.

**My question**

Suppose that we are given a Laplace transform in the form of a power series only: 
\begin{align}
F(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n s^n
\end{align}
where the radius of convergence is given by $|s|<r$.

How can we invert $F(s)$ from this the power series representation?   The issue I have here is that contour integration needs to be from  $c-iT$ to  $c+iT$  but the radius of convergence is finite.

Can the inversion be done here in some way?

**Edit:** Here is a concrete example.
Consider 
\begin{align}
F(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n s^n
\end{align}
where $a_n=2^{-n-2} (i(1+i)^{n+1}+(i-1)^n) $.  This power series has a radis of convergence $r=\sqrt{2}$.

In fact, the above power series corepsonds to a function
\begin{align}
F(s)= \frac{1}{1+(1+s)^2},
\end{align}
which has an inverse trasform given by
\begin{align}
f(t)= e^{-t} \sin(t) u(t)
\end{align}
where $u(t)$ is the step function.

However, if we don't know what the actual function is, how would we use the power series representation to find the inverse.

Comment: This is an interesting question seeing as a Laplace transform is basically the continuous version of a power series.

Comment: @Math1000 any idea on how to approach something like this?

Comment: Note that the $\lim_{T\to\infty}$ applies to the imaginary part of $c-iT$ and $c+iT$. So as long as we choose $c<r$, there is no problem with convergence.

Comment: @Math1000 Is that correct though?  The region of convergence of power series is a ball in a complex plane of radius $r$. Is in it the case that once $|c-iT|>r$ the power series no longer converges?

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of the power series as as real function. In that case I am no longer sure.

Comment: No there is no way to invert the power series directly, this is because the inverse Laplace transform of $s^n$ is $(-1)^n \delta^{(n)}(t)$ the distributional derivative of the Dirac delta.

Comment: You could maybe expand the integral in series before taking the limit, interchange summation, and see if it reduces to a formal Laurent series for an exponential function about infinity which you can then take the limit of. Everything I just said is probably mathematically invalid, but often these sort of formal manipulations work anyways.

Comment: @reuns Ok. I guess this problem is hopeless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question can be rephrased as

> When the Taylor series of $F(s)$ is known in a neighbourhood of $s=\alpha$, how can the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)$ be found?

For $\displaystyle{F(s)= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} f(t) dt}$, the region of convergence of $F(s)$ must be of the form $\text{Re } s>\sigma$ (call this set $H_\sigma$).

Theoretically, with knowledge of Taylor series of $F$ in a neighbourhood of $\alpha$, we can analytically continue $F$ to $H_\sigma$. However, Taylor series, which was born to have circular region of convergence, is hard to be analytically continued to half-planes.

Therefore, my idea is:

1. Conformally map $H_\sigma$ to the unit circle, as well as $\alpha$ to the origin.
2. Expand the 'conformally-mapped $F$' as a Maclaurin series.
3. Due to the absence of singularities in the unit circle, the Maclaurin series has radius of convergence $1$.
4. Inverse the conformal map. Now, the functional form of $F$ converges on $H_\sigma$.
5. Perform inverse Laplace transform.

---

> **Theorem** 
>   If $F(s)$, the Laplace transform of $f(t)$, has abscissa $\sigma$ and can be expanded as a $\sum^\infty_{j=0}a_j(s-\alpha)^j$ (where $\text{Re }\alpha>\sigma$), then
>   $$f(t)=u(t)\cdot\lambda e^{(\alpha-\lambda)t}\sum^\infty_{n=1}b_n\cdot \ell_n(\lambda t)$$
>   where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside step function and
>   $$\lambda=2(\text{Re }\alpha-\sigma)$$
>   $$b_n=\sum^n_{k=1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}a_k\lambda^k$$
>   $$\ell_n(x)=\frac{dL_n(x)}{dx}$$
>   *(NB: $L_n$ are [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials).)*

---

### Conformal mapping

All confomral maps from upper-half plane $\mathbb H$ to the unit disk $\mathbb D$ have the form
$$M(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-b}{z-\bar b}\qquad \theta\in\mathbb R, b\in \mathbb H$$

First, map $H_\sigma$ to $\mathbb H$ by $g(z)=i(z-\sigma)$ (equivalent to a leftward translation and 90-degree anticlockwise rotation). Then, map $\mathbb H$ to $\mathbb D$ by $m(z)=\frac{z-a}{z-\bar a}$, where $a=i(\alpha-\sigma)$.

You may check that these two maps together map $\alpha$ to $0$.

Hence,
$$F:H_\sigma\mapsto\mathbb C\implies F\circ g^{-1}\circ m^{-1}:\mathbb D\mapsto \mathbb C$$ (This could be a little counter-intuitive, but I will leave it to you to figure out.)

Here, $$m^{-1}(z)=\frac{\bar a z-a}{z-1}\qquad g^{-1}(z)=-iz+\sigma$$

Therefore, the 'conformally-mapped $F$' is 
$$F\circ g^{-1}\circ m^{-1}=F\left(\frac{(2\sigma-\bar\alpha)z-\alpha}{z-1}\right)$$
(by substituting in $a=i(\alpha-\sigma)$ and doing some algebra.)

---

### Maclaurin series expansion

Let $\lambda=\alpha+\bar\alpha-2\sigma=2(\text{Re }\alpha-\sigma)$.

Given that $\displaystyle{F(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (s-\alpha)^n}$, after some algebra, we have
$$F\left(\frac{(2\sigma-\bar\alpha)z-\alpha}{z-1}\right)
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n 2^n(\text{Re }\alpha-\sigma)^n\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^n 
\equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n 
$$

where

$$b_n=\sum^n_{k=1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}a_k\lambda^k$$

This Maclaurin series necessarily has radius of convergence $1$.

---

### Inverse conformal mapping

Since $F\circ g^{-1}\circ m^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$, we have
$$F(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(m\circ g(s))^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\left(\frac{s-\alpha}{s+\bar\alpha-2\sigma}\right)^n$$

which is valid on the entire $H_\sigma$.

---

### Inverse Laplace transform

(It is assumed $t>0$. The proof for $t<0$ is trivial.)

Note that $\lim_{s\to+\infty}F(s)=0$, therefore $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}b_n=0$$

Thus, $F(s)$ can be rewritten as 
$$F(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\left[\left(\frac{s-\alpha}{s+\bar\alpha-2\sigma}\right)^n-1\right]$$

By residue theorem and Jordan's lemma,
$$\frac1{2\pi i}\lim_{T\to\infty}\int^{\sigma+iT}_{\sigma-iT}\left[\left(\frac{s-\alpha}{s+\bar\alpha-2\sigma}\right)^n-1\right]e^{st}ds=\text{Res}_n$$

where

$$\text{Res}_{n}=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 2\sigma-\bar\alpha}\frac{d^{n}}{dz^{n}}(z-\alpha)^{n+1}e^{zt}=\lambda e^{(\alpha-\lambda)t}\sum^n_{r=1}\binom{n}{r}\frac{(-1)^r(\lambda t)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}$$

To this end, we notice the resemblance with [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) $$L_n(x)=\sum^n_{r=0}\binom{n}{r}\frac{(-1)^rx^r}{r!}$$

In essence, $$\text{Res}_{n}=\lambda e^{(\alpha-\lambda)t}\frac{dL_n(x)}{dx}\bigg\vert_{x=\lambda t}:=\lambda e^{(\alpha-\lambda)t}\ell_n(\lambda t)$$

and hence the theorem.

---

### Example

Let us verify the theorem for $\mathcal L\{u(t)\}(s)=\frac1s$.

> Suppose we know that $$F(s)=\sum^\infty_{j=0}(-1)^j(s-1)^j$$ Then  what is $f(t)$?

Here, $\sigma=0$, $\alpha=1$, $\lambda=2$, $a_n=(-1)^n$.

Hence, 
$$\begin{align}
b_n
&=\sum^n_{k=1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(-1)^k2^k \\
&=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\binom{n-1}{k}(-1)^{k+1}2^{k+1} \\
&=2\cdot(-1)^{n}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\binom{n-1}{k}(-1)^{n-1-k}2^{k} \\
&=2\cdot(-1)^{n}(2-1)^{n-1}=2\cdot(-1)^n
\end{align}
$$

According to the theorem,
$$f(t)=u(t)\cdot 4e^{-t}\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^n\ell_n(2t)$$

Recall the generating function of Laguerre polynomials 
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}z^nL_n(x)=\frac1{1-z}e^{-zx/(1-z)}$$
Thus,
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}z^n\ell_n(x)=-\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}e^{-zx/(1-z)}$$

Consequently,
$$f(t)=u(t)\cdot 4e^{-t}\cdot \frac1{4}e^{2t/2}=u(t)$$ as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Very cool answer. I will try to go over this soon and ask some questions.   Meanwhile, it would be cool if you could finish the last step

Comment: @Boby please see my latest edit.

Comment: I have a power series that converges everywhere. Can I still use your theorem? Analogously to the power series expansion of the exponential function (r=Infinity and neighbourhood alpha=0) As far as I can tell sigma =-Infinity and alpha=0 which makes your formula hard to use. I'm a physicist and no expert at all so I would really appreciate your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Concretely the only hope you have is to find a smooth function $g$ such that $G(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)e^{-st}dt$ is analytic at $s=0$ and such that $$f(t)=\lim_{K\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^K (-1)^k b_k g^{(k)}(t)\qquad \text{converges in } L^1_{loc} \text{ or in the sense of distributions}$$ where $$\frac{F(s)}{G(s)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k s^k$$
In that case $f(t)$ is the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)$

Comment: Thanks. I don't follow every think but will think about this approach.  Could maybe outline how this would work with a power series that I provided?

Comment: No. It works with $f(t)=e^{-t^2}, g(t)= e^{-2t^2}$ because the quotient of their bilateral Laplace transform is $F(s)/G(s)= \sqrt{1/2} e^{s^2/4}/e^{s^2/8}$ which is entire and rapidly decreasing on vertical lines, from the power series at $0$ we have as its inverse Laplace transform the series of dirac deltas derivatives $\sum_kb_k(-1)^n\delta^{(k)}$ which converges only in the sense of analytic functionals but when taking the convolution with $g(t)$ we obtain $\sum_k b_k (-1)^n g^{(k)}$ which does converge in the sense of distributions, to $f$. Finding $g$ is not much easier than finding $f$.